# Error bringing in the auxiliary scalar field in the Wess Zumino model

Tags: supersymmetry

I'm trying to understand the Wess Zumino model in section 3.1 of Stephen P. Martin's "A Supersymmetry Primer" hep-ph/9709356. However, I learned the representation theory of SL(2,C) from Wu Ki Tung's book "Group Theory in Physics", so I prefer to stick to certain notations for dotted and undotted spinors that I've understood rather than follow Martin's notation exactly. Everything was going well, working through Martin's explanation, but using different notational conventions, until the introduction of the auxiliary complex scalar field $F$, where I cannot persuade the variation in the Lagrangian for the auxilary fields $\delta L_{aux}$ to cancel the additional variation $\delta L_{ferm}$ from the spinor field. I'll explain my working and, hopefully, someone will be able to spot my error. I'll start with the notation and then give the erroneous calculation.

**Notation**

A contravariant Weyl spinor $\psi^{A}$ transforms as $\psi'^{A}=g^{A}_{\ \ B}\psi^{B}$ where $g^{A}_{\ \ B}$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix rep. The complex conjugate matrix rep transforms as $\psi'_{\dot{A}}=g{*}_{\dot{A}}^{\ \ \dot{B}}\psi_{\dot{B}}$ . So, if one starts with a contravariant spinor $\psi^{A}$ and takes the complex conjugate, the result is a quantity which transforms as a spinor with a downstairs dotted index. In other words, $(\psi^{A})^{*}=\psi^{*}_{\dot{A}}$ . A covariant spinor is $\psi_{A}$. It transforms with a matrix $g^{-T}$. The complex conjugate of a covariant spinor is a quantity with an upstairs dotted index $\psi^{\dot{A}}$ and it transforms with a matrix $g^{-\dagger}$. The two undotted reps are equivalent and are related by the SL(2,C) invariant Levi-Civita tensor, $\psi^{A}=\epsilon^{AB}\psi_{B}$, $\psi_{A}=\psi^{B}\epsilon_{BA}$. The equivalent dotted reps are related by $\psi_{\dot{A}}=\epsilon_{\dot{A}\dot{B}}\psi^{\dot{B}}$, $\psi^{\dot{A}}=\psi_{\dot{B}}\epsilon^{\dot{B}\dot{A}}$.

The spinor corresponding to a four vector is the Hermitian matrix,
$$
 X^{\dot{A}}_{\ \ B}=(\sigma_{\mu})^{\dot{A}}_{\ \ B}x^{\mu}
$$
where the $\sigma_{\mu}$ are Pauli matrices. The spinor  form of the four-momentum operator is,
$$
\hat{p}^{\dot{A}}_{\ \ B}=(\sigma_{\mu})^{\dot{A}}_{\ \ B}\eta^{\mu\lambda}i\partial_{\lambda}
$$
**Calculation**

The fermionic kinetic term in the Wess Zumino Lagrangian is $L_{ferm}=\psi^{*}_{\dot{A}}\hat{p}^{\dot{A}}_{\ \ B}\psi^{B}$. The scalar kinetic term is $L_{scalar}=\eta^{\mu\lambda}\partial_{\mu}\phi^{*}\partial_{\lambda}\phi$. Under a supersymmetry transformation, the variation of the scalar and fermionic parts is zero modulo a total derivative. However, the commutator of two supersymmetry transformations only closes on-shell. In order to make the algebra close off shell an auxiliary scalar field $F$ is introduced with Lagrangian $L_{aux}=F^{*}F$. The action of an infinitesimal supersymmetry transformation with spinor parameter $\epsilon^{A}$ is now,
$$
\delta \psi^{A}=-\epsilon^{*\dot{B}}\hat{p}_{\dot{B}}^{\ \ A}\phi+\epsilon^{A}F
$$
The first term produces a $\delta L_{ferm}$ which already cancels the variation $\delta L_{scalar}$. The second term has been added to cancel the variation $\delta L_{aux}$ coming from the auxiliary field. Let's calculate the fermionic variation from the added term and the variation of the auxilary field.
$$
\delta L=\delta\psi^{*}_{\dot{A}}(\hat{p}^{\dot{A}}_{\ \ B}\psi^{B})+\psi^{*}_{\dot{A}}(\hat{p}^{\dot{A}}_{\ \ B}\delta\psi^{B})+\delta F^{*}F+F^{*}\delta F\\
=\epsilon^{*}_{\dot{A}}F^{*}(\hat{p}^{\dot{A}}_{\ \ B}\psi^{B})+\psi^{*}_{\dot{A}}(\hat{p}^{\dot{A}}_{\ \ B}\epsilon^{B}F)+\delta F^{*}F+F^{*}\delta F
$$ 
The first and fourth terms on the RHS can be made to cancel if one says that the auxiliary field transforms as $\delta F=-\epsilon^{*}_{\dot{A}}(\hat{p}^{\dot{A}}_{\ \ B}\psi^{B})$. Now, $\delta F^{*}$ must be,
$$
\delta F^{*}=-\epsilon^{A}(\hat{p}^{*})_{A}^{\ \ \dot{B}}\psi^{*}_{\dot{B}}
=-\epsilon^{A}(\hat{p}^{*T})^{\dot{B}}_{\ \ A}\psi^{*}_{\dot{B}}
=-\epsilon^{A}(\hat{p}^{\dagger})^{\dot{B}}_{\ \ A}\psi^{*}_{\dot{B}}
=\epsilon^{A}\hat{p}^{\dot{B}}_{\ \ A}\psi^{*}_{\dot{B}}
$$
The last result used the fact that $\hat{p}^{\dot{B}}_{\ \ A}$ is anti-Hermitian since it's composed of Hermitian Pauli matrices with a factor $i$. Now, armed with $\delta F^{*}$, the second and third terms in the variation should cancel. The second term has to be differentiated by parts to bring out $F$ on its own. With neglect of the total derivative coming from the differentiation by parts, the second and third terms are,
$$
\delta L=-(\hat{p}^{\dot{A}}_{\ \ B}\psi^{*}_{\dot{A}})\epsilon^{B}F+\epsilon^{A}(\hat{p}^{\dot{B}}_{\ \ A}\psi^{*}_{\dot{B}})F
$$
If the spinor field $\psi^{*}_{\dot{A}}$ and the infinitesimal spinor parameter $\epsilon^{A}$ are complex numbers then the variation (after a change of dummy indices) is zero. However, these spinors are supposed to be Grassmann valued so that there is a sign change when their order is swapped in one term to bring the factors into the same order in both terms. The Grassmann nature of the spinors is needed because I found that the commutor of two supersymmetry transformations does not even close on shell when the spinors are assumed to be complex valued.

So, my question is, how do I change things so that the last variation is zero with Grassmann valued $\psi^{A},\epsilon^{A}$?

Comment: Are you saying that $\psi^*_\dot{A}$ and $\epsilon^\dot{A}$ are supposed to anti-commute? $\psi^*_\dot{A}$ is a RH (depending on your convention) chiral spinor field, and so would commute with a grassman variable $\epsilon^\dot{A}$.

Comment: @InertialObserver : I think that  these variables are anti-commuting. I assume $\psi\epsilon=-\epsilon\psi$ regardless of the position or type of the indices. Is this wrong?

Comment: I believe so. It looks like here $\Psi^*_\dot{A}$ is the spinor component of the superfield (which is why you are calculating its variation; you would never do that for a Grassman variable). If you go back to the definition of Grassman variable it is $\{\theta^\alpha, \bar{\theta}_\dot{\alpha}\} = 0$ . The spinor field is **contracted** with the Grassman variable in the superfield.

Comment: Take a look at equations (57) and (45) of Lykken's Introduction to Supersymmetry. In general, it's a bit terse, but quite good. Definitely good to have by your side as you learn SUSY. The superfield is a complex scalar (eqn 57),  and as such it **must** be that the grassman variable is contracted with the spinor field. That is, $\theta\psi = \theta^\alpha \psi_\alpha$.